# Normal over Binomial Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

```
During bottling 3% of the bottles break. Calculate the range in which the 
amount of undamaged bottles lies with a probability of 95% and if 3000 
bottles were filled.
```

I tried to solve that question with the binomial as well as the normal distribution.

**Binomial Distribution**

$\mathrm{qbinom}\left(\dfrac{1+95\%}{2}, n, (1-3\%)\right)-n\cdot(1-3\%)$ 
if $\mathrm{qbinom}$ is the inverse cumulative probability-function of my math software and has  this signature $\mathrm{qbinom}(p, \text{size}, \text{prob})$

I get a $\Delta x$ of $18$ and therefore my range is: $(2892;2928)$

**Normal Distribution**

If I calculate it with the normal distribution, however, I get a completely different range:

$$\mu=3000\cdot(1-3\%)$$

$$\sigma=\sqrt{3000\cdot(3\%)\cdot(97\%)}$$

$$\Delta x= F^{-1}(\frac{1+95\%}{2})\cdot\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{3000}} = 0,334\ldots$$

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I noticed that if I omit the last $\sqrt{3000}$ in the denominator I get $18,312\ldots$ but that might just be a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not coincidence. The variance in the number of broken bottles (or surviving bottles) is $3000(0.03)(0.97)$. The standard deviation is the square root of that.
Since the random variable you are studying is the number of surviving bottles, the appropriate mean is $2910$, and the appropriate standard deviation is $\sqrt{3000(0.03)(0.97)}$.

**Remark:** When you divided by $\sqrt{3000}$, you found the standard deviation of the **proportion** of broken (or unbroken) bottles. The *proportion* is not what you are working with when you want to find information about the *number* of bottles. You *could* work with proportion, but then you would need to multiply your proportion confidence interval by $3000$ to get to numbers of bottles.